# servlet page calling database from another pc

Tags: database, servlets

**sir i am developing my final year b.tech project.**
i am developing project in jsp and i have project code on one pc and i am trying to connect to oracle database which is on another pc.
i am calling jsp page to servlet page and servlet page having the database coding
i have written this code.

```
import javax.servlet.*;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;      
import java.sql.*; 
import oracle.sql.*;   
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
public class login extends HttpServlet  
{    
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws 
       IOException, ServletException{    
    String s1 = request.getParameter("username");

String s2 = request.getParameter("password");

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
      // Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin: @ip:1521:xe", "system",    
 "oracle");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("insert into data values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"')");
System.out.println("data inserted");

  }
    catch(Exception e)
  {    
    System.out.println(e); 
    }    
        }     
}
```

it is just an example of inserting.
i dont know whether im doing right.
it is also saying **oracle.sql** package is not available
what should to do pls help me.

Comment: sir this coding is enough for interacting to another pc's database or i should go towards socket programming.

Comment: what is the ip-address of the machine where oracle runs ? do you realy try with `jdbc:oracle:thin: @ip:1521:xe` ?? if then replace `ip` with the actual ip. You should be having something like `jdbc:oracle:thin: @10.0.100.4:1521:xe` where `10.0.100.4` is the ip of the oracle machine, better yet use the `host-name` instead. it is most likely that the ip changes than the host-name.

Comment: sir i know that i have to use ip or the host name.sir can it simply connect with jdbc odbc driver.or i have to only use thin driver? and what about **oracle.sql** and **oracle.jdbc.driver**

Answer (score 0):

In java you need only the jdbc driver, place it in the classpath of your application, register the driver and get a connection.

The driver class `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` you are using does not look familiar to me, you should be using `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`.

Note that Oracle provides two jdbc drivers [thin](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver) and [oci](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#OCI_driver). There is a little difference in the url you need to provide to get a connection.

(Never heard of this [one](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#KPRB_driver) :/)

Comment: sir i think for thin driver **ojdbc6** is required. how do i set the class path of ojdbc6 fror my project?

Comment: what ide are you using ? what app-server are you using ?

Comment: sir i am coding on **notepad** and server is **tomcat**

Comment: **jdk1.6** and **tomcat 7.0**

Comment: sir tell me all the required process for using **oracle thin dirver** so that i can use **oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver**   pls sir

Comment: @user2084588, Wow notepad!! Why not use something better ?? [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) for example. You'll see it is light years more confortable than only `notepad + javac`. To answer your question you need to set the classpath for two things: 1st using the `-classpath` option and specify both `ojdbc6.jar` and `servlet-api.jar`, 2nd: for running the application on tomcat put the jar file for the jdbc driver in the directory `lib` in the tomcat home (where tomcat is installed). If you need to know how to setup Eclipse let me know, and btw use @<nickname> to notify a user.

Comment: @user2084588, 1st is for the compiler `javac`. Here is a [guide](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html) how to setup `Eclipse` with `Tomcat`. Have a look at `Quick start`